# Visual Studio, GIT, and SQL Scripts

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, source-control, git

I am trying to figure out a way to have all of our random SQL scripts that we write under source control. I am already using SSDT for the database project. This is not for these sort of scripts. It is for all the other random queries that we run over time. Before we put them in a stored procedure. Or the other scripts that just don't really fit as a SP.

How can I bring my non SSDT Sql scripts under source control using Visual Studio?

Comment: For those closing b/c of shopping list - I am open to editing my question. I would just need guidance on what to add/remove.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can, that's what I do with my projects. Have a look:

Create a new Project, I use SQL Server Database Project because I generally end up adding more than just scripts.

[image]

Add items. Scripts in this case.

[image]

Go the Team Explorer and select GitHub (or TFS if that's what you're going to work with)

[image]

I'm going to create a new Private Repository.

[image]

Done!

[image]

Now Push the changes...

[image]

Finish!

[image]

Comment: I don't know how I missed that script part. I'm going to test this morning and mark it as accepted if it works. Thank you so much!